# create cdbcriteria for inner query in yii?

Tags: yii

I want to create my query with cdbcriteria in YII , **with out using createCommand.**

```
select count(*) count
from (select id,player_id,goals_scored,if(goals_scored>0,@counter:=@counter+1,@counter:=0)    count from player_stats, (select @counter:=1) b 
where player_id='1000099' and @counter>0 order by id desc) f
```

**How can  I create correct SQL query in YII syntax?**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `CDbCriteria` for this? You probably need the [`DAO`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) and something like this:

```
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
select count(*) count
from (select id,player_id,goals_scored,if(goals_scored>0,@counter:=@counter+1,@counter:=0)    count from player_stats, (select @counter:=1) b 
where player_id='1000099' and @counter>0 order by id desc) f
")->queryScalar();
```

Usually CDbCriteria is used with ActiveRecord models but I don't see how it would be applicable in this particular case. If not, please show the full code sample.

Comment: I know that using createCommand , I can do it. But I want to do it with CDbCriteria or any other option other then createCommand.

Comment: I think that you can do. The @Veseliq solution is correct. He was faster than me :P

Comment: But I do not want to do this with createCommand. Please, Is there a another  way to do that in YII?

Comment: How do you want to do it with `CDbCriteria`? That object is tightly connected with Yii's `AR` and is not suitable for scalar values. Show more code.

Comment: @Veseliq so, we can not do it without  using createCommand in YII ?

Comment: I have an issue in Yii, where I also would need to use the criteria and not the createcommand, becasue I have one object query(using the findAll() method), which I need to "transform" into a scalar query. e.g. normally it creates a "select a1,a2,a3,a4.. from ... and I need to removed all those fields and exchange them e.g. for "select count(*) from".

Comment: You are probably looking for Yii's STAT Relations: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query